# How Do I stop This Program Python

Tags: python, while-loop, exit

When I run this in IDLE and I type 0 for the response, It prints the message but it does not stop the program. I thought setting keepGoing to False would stop it but I do not know whats going on. Please help

```
""" crypto.py
Implements a simple substitution cypher
"""

alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key =   "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"

def main():
  keepGoing = True
  while keepGoing:
    response = menu()
    if response == "1":
      plain = input("text to be encoded: ")
      print(encode(plain))
    elif response == "2":
      coded = input("code to be decyphered: ")
      print (decode(coded))
    elif response == "0":
      print ("Thanks for doing secret spy stuff with me.")
      keepGoing = False
    else:
      print ("I don't know what you want to do...")
    return main()

def menu():
    print("Secret decoder menu")
    print("0) Quit")
    print("1) Encode")
    print("2) Decode")
    print("What do you want to do?")
    response = input()
    return response

def encode(plain):
    plain = plain.upper()
    new = ""
    for i in range(len(plain)):
        y = alpha.index(plain[i])
        new += key[y]
    return new

def decode(coded):
    coded = coded.upper()
    x = ""
    for i in range(len(coded)):
        z = key.index(coded[i])
        x += alpha[z]
    return x

main()
```

Comment: Try raising a value error or using a break statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are calling main() again, before exiting the while loop, and restarting the program:

```
def main():
    keepGoing = True
    while keepGoing:
        response = menu()
        if response == "1":
            plain = input("text to be encoded: ")
            print(encode(plain))
        elif response == "2":
            coded = input("code to be decyphered: ")
            print (decode(coded))
        elif response == "0":
            print ("Thanks for doing secret spy stuff with me.")
            keepGoing = False
        else:
            print ("I don't know what you want to do...")
#      return main()  # <-- delete this line
```

A better design, as suggested by @Barmar, is to use a `while True` loop, and a `break` statement to exit upon reaching a certain condition:

```
def main():
    while True:
        response = menu()
        if response == "1":
            plain = input("text to be encoded: ")
            print(encode(plain))
        elif response == "2":
            coded = input("code to be decyphered: ")
            print (decode(coded))
        elif response == "0":
            print ("Thanks for doing secret spy stuff with me.")
            break
        else:
            print ("I don't know what you want to do...")
```

Comment: Actually he's calling it BEFORE repeating the `while` loop.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed, i got fooled by the 2 space indent. Thanks.

Comment: Also a simple `return` would end the program when the recursion is removed. No need for `keepGoing`.

Comment: And a `break` statement would end the loop if you want to do something before exiting. I wish I knew who was teaching people to use `while <variable>:` instead of `while True:`.

Comment: I added your valuable suggestion @Barmar.